# Plotting words in text clustering using python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, unsupervised-learning

I've got the result shown in below figure for my clustering.

[image]

Are there any libraries which are similar to fvid_clusters which could produce the plots as shown below ? (USING PYTHON)

[image]

Comment: did you try matplotlib

Comment: Which vectorizer did you use to convert words to vectors ?

Comment: @mujjiga I use TfidfVectorizer

Comment: @TuckYew did you got any way to create diagram as above?

Comment: Did you solve the problem? @Rehan

Comment: No we couldn't.. there are no free tools out there which gives a good plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plots are not exactly like you show, but there two tools that I like to use in order to explore the result of text clustering (both have binds for Python).

**Termite**: http://vis.stanford.edu/papers/termite

[image: Termite]

**UMAP**: https://umap-learn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Here is the result of a topic modeling performed with NMF (from my thesis) using the [BBC Sports dataset](http://mlg.ucd.ie/datasets/bbc.html).

[image: BBC Sports]

Comment: can you please share the code? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1: Vectorize the words into vectors (each of size n)
- Step 2: Use kmean to cluster them into k clusters
- Step 3: Run PCA on vectors produced in step 1 and reduce them to 2 dimensions (say x,y)
- Step 4: Plot the words at the location (x, y) where (x,y) are the dimensions reduced by the PCA from its full size vector of size n. Color the word corresponding to which cluster it falls identified in step 2 (use one color per cluster).